Lee's definition of a consistently oriented basis for a real vector space $V$ of dimension $n\geq 1$
Let $V$ be a real vector space of dimension $n\geq 1$. Lee defines in his book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds chapter 15 that

We say that two ordered bases $(E_1,\dots,E_n), (\tilde{E}_1,\dots,\tilde{E}_n)$ for $V$ are consistently oriented if the transition matrix $(B_i^j)$ defined by $E_i = B_i^j\tilde{E}_j$ has positive determinant.

Correct me if I am wrong and/or if I don't understand the notation, but to me this definition seems to assume a priori that elements of the two bases are scalar multiples of exactly on other element of the other basis? So we couldn't really use this definition to talk about whether the basis $((1, 0), (0,1))$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and its rotated version by an angle $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ are consistently oriented?

Do you know Einstein notation?

@Rmal And this solves the issue. Thanks!
